# How to perform an SQLite query within an Android application?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to use this query upon my Android database, but it does not return any data.  Am I missing something?

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String select = "Select _id, title, title_raw from search Where(title_raw like " + "'%Smith%'" +
    ")";        
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, 
            select, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;
```

Comment: try this for your correct query. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17925238/6125132

Answer (score 112, accepted):

This will return you the required cursor

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"_id", "title", "title_raw"}, 
                "title_raw like " + "'%Smith%'", null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Do you just pass `null` if you want the `where` condition to be "everything"?

Comment: @Matt: Yes, simply pass null for no where caluse

Comment: To improve caching, you can separate selection and selection-arguments like this: `..., "title_raw like ?", new String[]{"'%Smith%'"}, ...`. Source: [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: @sulai Where is the connection between SQLiteDatabase and ContentResolver? The link to SQLite is: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase There they don't say anything about caching. I think separate arguments should be used against sql injection. Otherwise they're not very important, I think.

Answer (score 58):

Alternatively, db.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs) exists.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select, null);
```

Answer (score 27):

This will also work if the pattern you want to match is a variable.

```
dbh = new DbHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();

Cursor c = db.query(
    "TableName", 
    new String[]{"ColumnName"}, 
    "ColumnName LIKE ?", 
    new String[]{_data+"%"}, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null
);

while(c.moveToNext()){
    // your calculation goes here
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I came here for a reminder of how to set up the query but the existing examples were hard to follow. Here is an example with more explanation.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

String table = "table2";
String[] columns = {"column1", "column3"};
String selection = "column3 =?";
String[] selectionArgs = {"apple"};
String groupBy = null;
String having = null;
String orderBy = "column3 DESC";
String limit = "10";

Cursor cursor = db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit);
```

Parameters

- `table`: the name of the table you want to query
- `columns`: the column names that you want returned. Don't return data that you don't need.
- `selection`: the row data that you want returned from the columns (This is the WHERE clause.)
- `selectionArgs`: This is substituted for the `?` in the `selection` String above.
- `groupBy` and `having`: This groups duplicate data in a column with data having certain conditions. Any unneeded parameters can be set to null.
- `orderBy`: sort the data
- `limit`: limit the number of results to return

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this works for my code
name is a String:

```
cursor = rdb.query(true, TABLE_PROFILE, new String[] { ID,
    REMOTEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, GENDER, AGE, DOB,
    ROLEID, NATIONALID, URL, IMAGEURL },                    
    LASTNAME + " like ?", new String[]{ name+"%" }, null, null, null, null);
```