# Android - Cursor result search string error, need search DISPLAY_NAME for match

Tags: java, android

I need to search the DISPLAY_NAME field 1st and last name and have tried this code:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); 
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,     ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " like %?%", new String[]{ results.get(0) }, null);
```

if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

I get error in log cat from the %'s in the cursor line.
Any advise would be appreciated. ??

Comment: will it still search both first & last name for number...

Comment: what does %?% do in this context ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContentResolver.query()` puts `' '` around substitute for question mark, so what you need is

```
Cursor cur = cr.query(
     ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
     null,
     ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " like ?", 
     new String[]{ "%" + results.get(0) + "%"}, 
     null);
```

Comment: this works, but pulls up all the available contacts for keyword. It starts calling 1st contacts, I hit end call..then it auto starts to dial 2nd #, then i hit end... and so on.. I thought the .get(0) would take care of that. Any idea please?

Comment: i can't really tell out of context, but in boundaries of this question you can use little hack to limit query result to one row: add `ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME ASC LIMIT 1` instead of `null` for you `cr.query()`. this will result in query like **SELECT** ... **ORDER BY** _display_name ASC LIMIT 1_

Comment: how can i post results to a list for user to pick from? ..can we continue this in chat? Thank u!

Comment: take a look at android documentation for [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) and [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) , and if you run into trouble you can post a separate question

Answer (score 0):

Try to put single quotes "'%?%'"

[How to perform an SQLite query within an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243199/sqlite-query-in-android-application)

hope this helps. tyvm.

If you want to use ? as a your parameter you might want to create a dynamic built
SQL string beforehand and run it later.

Answer (score 0):

According to what i can gather from:

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php

it looks like you have to encapsulate your like part like so:

```
"like '%?%'"
```