# Fetching Android MSISDN value

Tags: android

I have a query. Can someone please guide me how to get my MOBILE MSISDN Number. Is there any sample application for fetching/ displaying the MSISDN number. I need to get the MSISDN number. Any sample project will be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't done much of any search yet. So, please have a look here - I hope this will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243199/sqlite-query-in-android-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been covered in some topics, namely: [Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/get-phone-number-in-android-sdk) .

However, bear in mind that this doesn't always work. With a couple of portuguese SIM cards at least, I wasn't able to retrieve the phone number using these methods.

Quoting from @Johan's answer in that topic:

> There is no guaranteed solution to this problem because the phone
>   number is not physically stored on all SIM-cards, or broadcasted from
>   the network to the phone. This is especially true in some countries
>   which requires physical address verification, with number assignment
>   only happening afterwards. Phone number assignment happens on the
>   network - and can be changed without changing the SIM card or device
>   (e.g. this is how porting is supported).
>
> I know it is pain, but most likely the best solution is just to ask
>   the user to enter his/her phone number once and store it.