# search in listview when i had database

Tags: android, listview

I have Database but i don't kwow how to use search in listview. i search internet but i use "String" but I have a database so i can't use string please help to use search in listview to load data from the database instead of setting String products [ ] = { } a fixed String

```
  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    wordAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Word>(this, R.layout.list_item,
            R.id.product_name);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);
     dbHandler=new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());


     inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            MainActivity.this.wordAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

        }


        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
        //   TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        //   TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }
    });  

    and this is database



private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MYDB1",
        TABLE_TUVUNG="tuvung",
        KEY_ID = "id",
        KEY_THEM = "them",
        KEY_NGHIA = "nghia",
        KEY_LOAI = "loai",
        KEY_NGAY = "ngay";
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TUVUNG + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_THEM + " TEXT," + KEY_NGHIA + " TEXT," + KEY_LOAI + " TEXT," + KEY_NGAY + " TEXT)");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TUVUNG);

    onCreate(db);
}

public void createContact(Word contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_THEM, contact.getthem());
    values.put(KEY_NGHIA, contact.getnghia());
    values.put(KEY_LOAI, contact.getloai());
    values.put(KEY_NGAY, contact.getngay());

    db.insert(TABLE_TUVUNG, null, values);
    db.close();
}



public Word getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TUVUNG, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_THEM, KEY_NGHIA, KEY_LOAI,KEY_NGAY }, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null );

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Word contact = new Word(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return contact;
}
public void deleteContact(Word contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_TUVUNG, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getid()) });
    db.close();
}
public void valuestact(Word contact){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put(KEY_THEM, contact.getthem());
     values.put(KEY_NGHIA, contact.getnghia());
     values.put(KEY_LOAI, contact.getloai());
     values.put(KEY_NGAY, contact.getngay());
    return;
    }



public int getwordsCount() {

    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TUVUNG, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    return count;
}
public int updateContact(Word contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_THEM, contact.getthem());
    values.put(KEY_NGHIA, contact.getnghia());
    values.put(KEY_LOAI, contact.getloai());
    values.put(KEY_NGAY, contact.getngay());

    int rowsAffected = db.update(TABLE_TUVUNG, values, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getid()) });
    db.close();

    return rowsAffected;
}

public List<Word> getAllwords() {
    List<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TUVUNG, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            words.add(new Word(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4)));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return words;
}
```

Comment: `search in listview when i had database` ... Search in the database, instead, and repopulate the listview after each search!

Answer (score 0):

Try this link it may solve your problem for
[search a value from sqlite database and retrieve in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924940/search-a-value-from-sqlite-database-and-retreive-in-listview)

i hope it will helps you...