# Android: How can I search data in sqlite database and display it in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

How can I display data in a ListView from my database through search using an EditText or maybe filter it. Can you tell what codes I need have to do it I think Im missing something because my codes don't search it just display my data it a ListView. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here are my codes:

DBListHelper

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.util.Log;

class DBlistHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.searching/databases/";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LPG.db";
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Recipes";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
private static final String COLUMN_RECIPE = "Recipe";
public static final String COLUMN_INGRIDIENTS = "Ingredients";
//public static final String COLUMN_PROCEDURE = "procedure";



public SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite;

private final Context myContext;

public DBlistHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION );
    this.myContext= context;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void createDatabase() {

    createDB();

}

public void createDB(){

    boolean dbExist = DBExists();

    if(!dbExist){

        this.getReadableDatabase();

        copyDBFromResource();

    }

}



private boolean DBExists() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    try{
        String databasePath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);
        db.setVersion(1);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        Log.e("SqlHelper", "database not found");
    }

    if (db != null){

        db.close();
    }

    return db != null ? true : false;

}



private void copyDBFromResource(){

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    String dbFilePath =  DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    try{

        inputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(dbFilePath);

        byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

        }

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e){

        throw new Error("Problem copying database from resource file.");
    }

}


public void openDatabase () throws SQLException {

    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    dbSqlite = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close () {

    if (dbSqlite !=null){

        dbSqlite.close();
    }

    super.close();

}

public Cursor getCursor() {

    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder ();

    queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);

    String [] asColumnsToReturn = new String [] { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_RECIPE, COLUMN_INGRIDIENTS};

    Cursor mCursor = queryBuilder.query(dbSqlite, asColumnsToReturn, null, null, null, null, "Recipe ASC");

    return mCursor;
}

public String getName (Cursor c){
    return(c.getString(1));


}

}
```

Main.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Main extends Activity {

private DBlistHelper dbrecipelistHelper = null;
private Cursor ourCursor = null;
private recipeAdapter adapter = null;

EditText inputSearch = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    try
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


    dbrecipelistHelper = new DBlistHelper(this);

    dbrecipelistHelper.createDatabase();

    dbrecipelistHelper.openDatabase();

    ourCursor=dbrecipelistHelper.getCursor();

    startManagingCursor(ourCursor);

    adapter = new recipeAdapter(ourCursor);

    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);


    //myListView.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());   

        e.printStackTrace();

    }



    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            Main.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
    });




}


class recipeAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    recipeAdapter(Cursor c){
        super(Main.this, c);
    }

    @Override
    public  void bindView (View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c)
    {
        recipeHolder holder = (recipeHolder)row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, dbrecipelistHelper);
    }
    @Override
    public  View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
        recipeHolder holder = new recipeHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return(row);
    }


}

static class recipeHolder {
    private TextView name=null;

    recipeHolder(View row){
        name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.recipeText);
    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor c, DBlistHelper r){
        name.setText(r.getName(c));
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Search for the values define edit text and implement text watcher in database enter a query as shown below:

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){ 

Cursor cusror;

cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DB_NAME + " WHERE " 
                + DB_NAME.id + " = " + DB_NAME.Id + " AND " + DB_NAME.Title +
                 " LIKE  '"+search.getText()+"%'");
```

check the values if you are getting the correct values return the cursor.
Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks but do i have to get all the data? I already display the listview I need and I want is to filter it using EditText.

Comment: I did not get you, filter in the sense?

Comment: Do you want only selected values from database?

Comment: I want to filter the listview that match any word or keyword I insert in an EditText. Like a search bar in the top of my ListView layout

Comment: Check the edited answer. Try to modify that and use it in your code.

Comment: yes like that. I want only selected values to be appear on my ListView

Comment: yes in db class.  Refer tis SO link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292569/android-how-can-i-search-data-in-sqlite-database-and-display-it-in-listview/29293574#29293574

Comment: Im a little bit confused using the codes. do I have to change the query in my DB class? and my textwatcher is in my main class.

Comment: yes, sorry for the wrong link check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924940/search-a-value-from-sqlite-database-and-retreive-in-listview

Comment: If this answer helped you can you please vote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since cursors **returns the number of rows** from the database being searched, you can use `.getCount()` on the cursor object to check if you found the data or not.

This would be my approach.

```
public Cursor fetchData(String arg1){


        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COL1,COL2},COL1 + "=?",new String[]{arg1},null,null,null );
        return cursor;
    }
```

and in the MainActivity class

```
MyDatabase myDatabase = new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext());
Cursor cursor = myDatabase.fetchData("FRANCE");

if(cursor.getCount()>0)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```