# List items (Titles) with inner List data(description) in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-webview

I  need to develop one android application like a mini book.
My design requirement is..  First page contains " 1 to 100 Headings " and Each Heading contains 100 number of paragraphs.

i need to search text in the all paragraphs..
and also need to "go directly to particular paragraph"..
for example.. i want to go 3rd heading to 67th paragraph location..if i enter in search box 3.67... then that paragraph page need to appear...

which logic is best for this design..
Listview ?  or  Recycle view ?  or Web view ?

Android Developer kings Please give your  friendly reply...

[This is my Application design requirement demo image..please click and see..to understan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cFUq.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
which logic is best for this design.. Listview ? or Recycle view ? or Web view ?
```

It's recommended that you use Recycler view over Listview specially in your context.

Web view? - I'm not sure why would you use web view. Unless you want to develop everything on javascript and html5 and render it on web view.

There are number of Api's for databases in android. like SQLite database , Realm database to store and retrieve data for paragraphs.

Search field would be the next step  - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924940/search-a-value-from-sqlite-database-and-retrieve-in-listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924940/search-a-value-from-sqlite-database-and-retrieve-in-listview/%22retrieve%20something%20fro%20database%22)

I would recommend you to start the application and follow a complete step by step process. Creating activities, fragments and layouts with recycler views & adapters and add the data to a database and then Search field.

**Then if you come across any blockers you can come back here a post a question. People in this community will help you if you show them what you have tried before posting a question, One of things I learnt up here.**

Hope it helps !

Comment: Super .. Thank u for ur Superb response...
I have another doubt..
Which method is best for Storing the paragraphs..
In Xml String..? or store txt file in RAW folder..?  or  SQlite database..?
and I need to go particular heading to particular paragraph..
How can i apply this type of search..?
  (Example : I need to go 5th heading 77th paragraph.. 
there is Two edit text ..   Heading number is enter in 1st edit text and Paragraph number is enter in 2nd Edit text....Then click enter..  display that specific location )   Please give me your suggestion...